# Ajax Post request example

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, key-value

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a simple ajax request example just so I can wrap my head around the whole idea. I tried testing an ajax request to search the word "rails" on github. So my code looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'www.github.com',
type: 'post',
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
data: {
    q: 'rails'
},
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

});
```

This request is responding with a 404 response. So, I'm just curious how are you supposed to know what the key names for the "data" element should be? When I inspected the search bar on github, it told me the name of the element was q. Hence why I used the key "q" and I wanted to search for say "rails". If anyone could help me with this example or perhaps provide a better one that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It should be `http://www.github.com` but this would throw an error because you can't request github. Check [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Do you have any other websites that could be used for an example?

Comment: Whats the purpose of doing this? Just create a file on your webserver, fill it with informations and call this one. Another way to get the content w/o CORS would be [cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php).

Answer (score 2):

Try to add http in your url, but, for security reason you can't do Ajax Crossdomain request without autorisation of the github.com domain in your case.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/